# How to I keep my faceting variable in the data while summarising and plotting?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have successfully managed to visualize the geographical origin of our students over time. The variable NYA_REGION_GROV represents names of different regions.

I first group my observations by Admissionround and then by region (since the different regions within an admissionround should add up to 100%).

I write:

```
fulldata%>%
group_by(ADMISSIONROUND_ID,NYA_REGION_GROV)%>%
summarise(antal=n())%>%
mutate(andel=antal/sum(antal))%>%
ungroup()%>%
ggplot(aes(x=ADMISSIONROUND_ID,y=andel,color=NYA_REGION_GROV, group=NYA_REGION_GROV))+geom_line()+
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

And I get:

[image]

Now I want to facet the data by my gender variable, "KON_SV".

```
fulldata%>%
group_by(ADMISSIONROUND_ID,NYA_REGION_GROV)%>%
summarise(antal=n())%>%
mutate(andel=antal/sum(antal))%>%
ggplot(aes(x=ADMISSIONROUND_ID,y=andel,color=NYA_REGION_GROV, group=NYA_REGION_GROV))+
geom_line()+
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+ 
facet_wrap(~KON_SV)
```

But I get an error message claiming that "At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `KON_SV`."

On closer inspection, it seems that only two of my original 66 variables (plus my new variables "antal" and "andel") are present in my plot object.

Does the group_by or summarise statements somehow remove variables that aren't used? How do I keep KON_SV in my data so I can use it as a faceting variable?

Small excerpt of data with only 3 variables:

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041), class = "Date"), 
    ADMISSIONROUND_ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("HT2016", 
    "HT2017", "HT2018", "HT2019"), class = "factor"), NYA_REGION_GROV = c("FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND"), KON_SV = c("kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", 
    "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", 
    "man", "man", "man", "man", "man")), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), groups = structure(list(start_date = structure(17041, class = "Date"), 
    .rows = list(1:20)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Large excerpt with 3 variables

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), 
    ADMISSIONROUND_ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("HT2016", "HT2017", 
    "HT2018", "HT2019"), class = "factor"), NYA_REGION_GROV = c("FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "oklart", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "oklart", 
    "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "oklart", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "oklart", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "oklart", "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "oklart", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", 
    "oklart", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "oklart", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "oklart", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "oklart", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", 
    "oklart", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "oklart", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "oklart", "oklart", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", 
    "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "oklart", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", 
    "oklart", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "oklart", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "oklart", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", 
    "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "oklart", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "oklart", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "oklart", "oklart", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "oklart", "oklart", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "oklart", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "oklart", "oklart", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "oklart", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "oklart", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", 
    "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "STORGÖTEBORG", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", 
    "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", "oklart", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "ÖVRIGA LANDET", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "STORGÖTEBORG", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", 
    "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", "oklart", 
    "oklart", "oklart", "STORGÖTEBORG", "BOHUSLÄN OCH DALSLAND", 
    "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET", "oklart", "oklart", "FYRSTADSOMRÅDET"), 
    KON_SV = c("kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", 
    "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "man", "man", "man", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", 
    "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", 
    "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", 
    "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", 
    "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "man", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", 
    "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", 
    "man", "man", "man", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", 
    "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", 
    "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", 
    "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", 
    "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", 
    "man", "man", "man", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "man", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", 
    "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "man", 
    "man", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", 
    "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", 
    "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", 
    "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", 
    "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", 
    "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", 
    "man", "man", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", 
    "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", 
    "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", 
    "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", 
    "man", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "man", "man", "kvinna", 
    "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", 
    "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", "man", 
    "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "kvinna", "man", "kvinna", 
    "man", "kvinna")), row.names = c(NA, -554L), groups = structure(list(
    start_date = structure(c(17041, 17405, 17776, 18140, NA), class = "Date"), 
    .rows = list(1:104, 105:220, 221:374, 375:506, 507:554)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You don't have ``KON_SV`` in your ``group_by``? You need to include in order to use it as a faceting variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add "KON_SV" in your initial `group_by`.
Therefore, you will get a factor column with the gender variable, allowing the faceting.

```r
fulldata %>%
  group_by(KON_SV, ADMISSIONROUND_ID,NYA_REGION_GROV) %>% #added KON_SV
  summarise(antal=n()) %>%
  mutate(andel = antal/sum(antal)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ADMISSIONROUND_ID, y = andel, color = NYA_REGION_GROV, group = NYA_REGION_GROV)) + 
geom_line() + 
facet_wrap(.~KON_SV)
```

Comment: I wrote an identical chunk of code 5 minutes after asking this question, I guess only talking/writing about stuff can make a difference!

I should comment that the placement of the faceting variable in the group_by statement really matters. It needs to be placed first I think wince its the percentages from each region within each admissionround within each gender which should add up to 100%

Anyways, accepting this as correct answer!